# after update the kernel ubuntu 12.04 wont boot

Tags: boot, kernel

After I got the Update manger ask me to update the kernel and after restar the only thing I got is a message with:

```
file can't be found...
```

and now the only way to boot is to chose the previews Linux in grub menu!

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: what is the update kernel version? can you give some detail please

Comment: I don't know but am sure it's the latest because I always do the update thing :)

Comment: use old kernel to boot, check my post here http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/06/how-to-remove-old-kernel-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: no problem! Enjoy ubuntu!

Comment: @penreturn you should answer the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When grub show up, select old kernel.

Next, type the command below to view / list all installed kernels on your system.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Find the **newest** kernel than your current kernel. When you know which kernel to remove, continue below to remove it.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

Finally, run the commands below to update grub2

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Reboot your system